# Как в результате запроса объединить дублирующиеся результаты нужного столбца чтобы они не повторялись?

Tags: sql, oracle

Прошу помочь в написании части селекта, дело в том, что я даже не знаю как в гугл задавать свой вопрос.

Мне необходимо, чтобы в результате запроса, который выдает, например, результат:

```
1 А
2 А
3 А
```

Выдавался результат подобного вида:

```
1 А
2 
3
```

или:

```
1 
2 А
3
```

Но суть в том, чтобы дублирующиеся результаты нужного столбца объединялись и встречались один раз.

Comment: Вообще это было бы лучше делать на клиенте. Если все таки в oracle, то что то типа `case when (row_number() over(partition by поле-с-буквой-A order by первое-поле)) = 1 then поле-с-буквой-A end` смотреть в гугле описание row_number и "оконных функций"

Comment: @Mike, в целом работает, а имеется ли возможность при выводе запроса ячейки, в которых было повторяющееся значение, еще и объединить?

Comment: @Mike, вообще есть и клиентский селект, если сможете помочь, я с радостью скину, ну и самому разобраться тоже было бы неплохо.

Comment: Это объединение чисто визуальный эффект. Визуальное оформление не имеет отношения к БД. БД только отдает данные, а как оно отображено на экране - это уже дело языка взаимодействующего с этим самым экраном

Answer (score 2):

В большинстве инструментов это достигается командой [BREAK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/BREAK.html):

```sql
break on val skip 1 
select * from tab 
order by id
/
        ID VAL   
---------- ------
         1 A     
         2       
         3       

         4 B     
         5       
         6
```